# angular js infinite iteration error

Tags: angularjs

I have encountered an error running angularjs calling a rest service. Details below.

Here is my app.js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').factory('weatherService',function($http){
    return {
        getWeather:function(city,country){
            var query = 'city=' + city + '&country=' + country;
            return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',{
                params: {
                    q:query
                }
            }).then(function(response){
                return response.data.weather[0].description;
            });
        }
    }
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('WeatherController',
    function($scope,weatherService){
        $scope.getWeather=function(city,country){
            $scope.WeatherDescription = "Fetching...";
            weatherService.getWeather(city,country).then(function(data){
                $scope.weatherDescription = data;
            }, function(data){
                $scope.weatherDescription = "Could not obtain data";
            });
        }
});
```

html code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <script src="../js/angular/angular.js" ></script>
    <script src="../js/app.js" ></script>
        <body ng-controller="WeatherController">
            {{getWeather('chicago','usa')}}
        </body>
</html>
```

I get a blank response in the page. When I open the console, I get this error:

```
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:63
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14281)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14506)
    at done (angular.js:9659)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:9849)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:9790)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11607
(anonymous) @ angular.js:8557
$apply @ angular.js:14508
done @ angular.js:9659
completeRequest @ angular.js:9849
requestLoaded @ angular.js:9790
angular.js:63 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

what could possible be wrong? Anyone can help? I am using version 1.6.1 by the way

Thank you.

Comment: I think it is because you called the `getWeather('chicago','usa')` function from interpolation. Once try calling it in controller and show the result in view(HTML).

Comment: what do you mean calling it from interpolation?

Comment: Calling from view is not problem, It will work, the problem is something else

Comment: Interpolation is always looking for value. But, it is not having data as it returns promise. So, digest cycle runs for many times to have some value. When it reaches many cycles, it throws error I think.

Comment: i changed body content to {{weatherDescription}} and error was eliminated. but i am getting a blank response. Shouldnt it be 'could not obtain data' if there was an error in the called rest service?

Comment: Try to log the value of `response.data.weather[0].description;` in the first line of `.then()` of the `$http` request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to how angular `$digest` cycles work, and how expressions are evaluated.

You have an expression `{{getWeather('chicago','usa')}}` in your HTML.  Whenever a `$digest` cycle occurs, this expression will be evaluated, and the function will be called.

The function is setting a value `$scope.WeatherDescription = "Fetching...";`, then calling an async function.  The change in `$scope.WeatherDescription` is then causing a new `$digest` iteration.  The new `$digest` iteration is encountering the expression, and firing off the function (again).  Even if the data comes back from the promise, it's *also* going to cause a property on `$scope` to change, which is going to cause (another) `$digest`, causing (another!) call to the function... This will essentially happen infinitely, which is why angular automatically preempts the processing after 10 cycles.

It is *sometimes* ok to trigger a function call in an expression, but in order for that to work, the function call needs to return a value, and also needs to not trigger the change to another property on `$scope` unrelated to the expression.

In your case, instead of using `$scope.WeatherDescription`, you would want to `return` the promise from your service.

Comment: i changed body content to {{weatherDescription}} and error was eliminated. but i am getting a blank response. Shouldnt it be 'could not obtain data' if there was an error in the called rest service? –

Comment: no, because if you change the expression to the *output* of the function, you still need to *trigger* the function somewhere.  If you called the function from your controller, then that could work....  otherwise, `{{weatherDescription}}` will always be empty, since the function (and the `$http` request) never happen.

Comment: i returned the weather description and changed the html back to {{getWeather('chicago','usa')}} and the digest error came back

Comment: are you still changing `$scope.WeatherDescription`?

Comment: weatherService.getWeather(city,country).then(function(data){
    var weatherDescription = data;
    return weatherDescription;
   }

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the example in plunker so that I can demonstrate a working example.

Comment: poking around with this a bit, it seems this is throwing `401 (Unauthorized)` in the `$http` method, which is never getting back to the outer promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a `$digest` is already in progress by checking `$scope.$$phase`.

```
weatherService.getWeather(city,country).then(function(data){
              if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.weatherDescription = data;
              }
           }, function(data){
              if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.weatherDescription = "Could not obtain data";
              } 
         });
```